# Adobe Brackets Wordpress hints / autocomplete

Tags: wordpress, autocomplete, adobe-brackets, code-hinting

so.. I am trying out Adobe Brackets as my editor right now and I really like it so far, but there is one thing I am missing and I wonder if there is an extension for that..

I mainly code php, css and javascript for wordpress themes / plugins etc. I was using sublime 3 before, where I had a plugin that, if I type a wordpress function name and use the autocomplete, automatically inserts the parameters of that function. So in sublime it looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0UIb.png

In Adobe Brackets I tried every wordpress extension that I found but I cant get the same result. The hints for wordpress functions do work but when I accept a hint it wont insert the parameters of that function https://i.stack.imgur.com/PROkB.png

So I wondered if anyone knows an extension that offers autocompletion like in the sublime screenshot. Or am I missing sth else to get that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't yet installed this, but I came across it today and will be trying it out myself. It's an extension for Brackets called "Brackets WordPress Hint". It looks like the repository hasn't been contributed to in a while, but I haven't (yet) found anything newer.

https://github.com/Tusko/brackets-wp-hint